# Remove Powershell Modules that Powershell does not think are installed

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

Im trying to get rid of the AzureRM modules from my machines.

If I run `Get-Module`, Azure RM does not show up in the list, but for example I can still run `Get-AzureRmActionGroup`, proving that the modules are still there.

Can anyone help guide me on cleaning this up so they are no longer there?

Or is there a way I can just reset Powershell back to how it was when it was first installed without any additional modules?

Comment: Did you download it and add it to your PowerShell profile? When you run `Get-Command Get-AzureRmActionGroup` does it say where it came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powershell loads the modules from the paths stored in the $env:PSModulePath environment variable. So at the shell prompt type, $env:PSModulePath and hit enter, that will give you the paths where the modules resides. You can then either manually go to those paths and just delete the directories for the modules you don't want. or you can write a script to find and delete the modules you don't want.